# Extracting a substring of variable length from a string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I need to extract a variable length decimal number from a string using c# and .NET. The input string is like `$PTNTHPR,352.5,N,2.3,N,4.6,N,16*`. I need the first occurrence of decimal number, i.e the 352.5 part. The numerical value ranges from `0.0` to `360.0` and I need that number from that string.

I searched a lot and got solution for a fixed length sub string but here I have variable length to extract. I have not tried with any code yet.

Comment: will the number always be between ','?? If so use split(',')

Comment: [String.Split Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) and [How to: Split Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes always in between ','.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is always in this format you can use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [decimal.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
var data = @"$PTNTHPR,352.5,N,2.3,N,4.6,N,16*";
var d = decimal.Parse(data.Split(new[]{','})[1]);

Console.WriteLine(d);
```

This is just a sample code to guide you. You should add additional exception handling logic to this, Also consider using [decimal.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you want to find the first occurance of decimal value you split the string and parse them one by one.

```
var data = @"$PTNTHPR,352.5,N,2.3,N,4.6,N,16*";
var splited = data.Split(new[]{','});
decimal? value = null;
foreach (var part in splited)
{
    decimal parsed;
    if (decimal.TryParse(part, out parsed))
    {
        value = parsed;
        break;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Comment: Thanks dotctor, your solution helped me lot. I wonder if I need all three decimal numbers then what to do? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

First occurence in any of the tokens? Use `String.Split` to separate them and LINQ to find the first. You can use `decimal.TryParse` to check if it's parsable:

```
decimal? firstParsableToken = "$PTNTHPR,352.5,N,2.3,N,4.6,N,16*".Split(',')
    .Select(s => s.TryGetDecimal(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo))
    .FirstOrDefault(d => d.HasValue);
```

Used this simple extension method to parse it to `decimal?`:

```
public static decimal? TryGetDecimal(this string item, IFormatProvider formatProvider = null, NumberStyles nStyles = NumberStyles.Any)
{
    if (formatProvider == null) formatProvider = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    decimal d = 0m;
    bool success = decimal.TryParse(item, nStyles, formatProvider, out d);
    if (success)
        return d;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is always comma separated, can you not use string.Split() to get each section, then use double.TryParse() to test if that part is numeric?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static string MyExtract(this string s)
    {
        return s.Split(',').First(str => Regex.IsMatch(str, @"[0-9.,]"));
    }
}
```

Use it like this: `string str = "$PTNTHPR,352.5,N,2.3,N,4.6,N,16*".MyExtract();`
Then convert it to double/decimal if you need it.

Comment: code only answer, what if the number does not contains `.`?

Comment: If delimiter in this string is a comma sign then number cannot contain commas. It just doesn't make sense

Comment: try this, "$PTNTHPR,352,N,2.3,N,4.6,N,16*", your code will return 2.3 instead of 352

Comment: He wrote : "I need the first occurrence of decimal number" is 352 looks like a decimal number to you?

Comment: yes, every integer is a decimal number, people here are not your enemy, they make suggestion to make answers and the community better.

Comment: also you have an unused `temp` variable in your code, and the OP wants a decimal, if you write a function to extract the string part then convert it to decimal and return it.

Comment: Yes, the numbers in the input string are always in decimal format with one digit after decimal point. I need the first one i.e. for the given (by me) input string the output should be 352.5

Comment: You can do it using my method (updated one) or dotctor's (it's great too)